# How do I make a SQL query using an array's multiple keys/values?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays, codeigniter

I have an array with keys and values like this:

```
Array ( [1] => 0 [3] => 0 )
```

I want to call a database where question_id = 1 and it's value is 0 and combine that with a query of question_id = 3 and it's value of 0. I am using Codeigniter.

I've tried:

```
foreach($array as $key=>$value){
    $this->db->where('question_id', $key);
    $this->db->where('value', $value);
    $this->db->from('movies_values');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    $res = $query->result();
    print_r($res);
    array_push($main_array,$res);
}
```

Comment: So what's happening?  I'd think you'd put the from above the wheres but outside of that I don't see anything.  Have you tried outputting your key and value to make sure they are being set to what you think they are being set to?  Also where is your $this->db->select?

Answer (score 1):

if i got you right try the below

```
$this->db->where_in('question_id',array_keys($array));
$this->db->where_in('value', array_values($array));
return $this->db->get('movies_values')->result();
```

**EDIT** 
try this if you want to check where clause in pairs

```
$count=0;
foreach($array as $key=>$value)
{
    $where=array('question_id' => $key, 'value' => $value);
    if($count==0)
        $this->db->where($where);
    else
        $this->db->or_where($where);
    $count++;
}
return $this->db->get('movies_values')->result();
```

that would produce

```
SELECT *
FROM movies_values
WHERE question_id = key1 AND value val1
OR question_id = key2 AND value val2
OR question_id = key3 AND value val3
```

ref : [Active Record](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html)

Comment: Or perhaps use [`array_keys()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) and [`array_values()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) instead of the `foreach`-loop.

Comment: that's even better and cleaner code thanks @Josso, i updated my answer

Comment: I'm trying to make sure the question_id and the value stay as pairs.

Comment: And I only want the ones returned that meet ALL of that criteria. Is it possible?